# Question about topological quotient and equivalence relation

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Can't solve this, does anyone have some hint for me?

> Consider the disjoint union $Y:=\mathbb{R} \cup \{ \infty \}$ with the non-Hausdorff topology given by:
> $$\mathscr{T}:=\{ \emptyset \} \cup \{ \mathscr{U}\cup \{ \infty \} : \mathscr{U} \text{ is open in }\mathbb{R} \text{ with respect to its usual topology} \}.$$
> Find a subspace $X\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, a equivalence relation $R$ in $X$, and $\pi:X\rightarrow Y$ a projection so that $Y$ is the topological quotient of $X$ module $R$. (Here, just draw the equivalence classes, without showing that $\pi$ is a topological quotient application).

Comment: Hint: can you find a subspace $A$ of $\Bbb{R}^2$ that is disjoint from the $x$-axis, such that $A \cap U \neq \emptyset$ for every open $U$ that contains some point of the $x$-axis?

Comment: that U open in $\mathbb{R}$ or in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Open in $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: The subspace $A=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 ; x\neq 0 \text{ and } y>0 \}$ is disjoint from the x-axis, but for any open U in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that contains some point of the x-axis, lets say $a$ is that point, it exists a ball $B(a,r) \subset U$ such that the ball conteins elements from $A$, so $A\cap U \neq \emptyset$. This set $A$ works?  How does it help me resolve the question?

Comment: Your $A$ inside $\Bbb{R}^2$ and $\{\infty\}$ inside $Y$ have a lot in common (if you identify $\Bbb{R} \subseteq Y$ with the $x$-axis). Can you construct a continuous surjective function from the union of $A$ and the $x$-axis onto $Y$?

Comment: But in this case, what is the equivalence relation that I use?

Comment: When you have the continuous surjective function, $f$ say, you can use it to get the equivalence relation (relate $x$ to $y$ if $f(x) = f(y)$).

Comment: if I take $X=\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2;y\geq0 \}$, $A=\{ (x,y)\in X; y>0 \}$, $A^c=\{ (x,y)\in X; y=0 \}$ (or $A^c=\{ (x,0); x\in \mathbb{R} \}$) and defined the function for all $a\in X$
    $$\pi:X \rightarrow Y$$
    $$\pi(a)=\left\{ \begin{align*}
        &x,  \quad \text{ if } a=(x,0) (a\in A^c) \\
        &\infty,  \quad \text{ if } a\in A
    \end{align*}\right.$$
    this works? I can't show that this $\pi$ is continuous

Comment: That's the right function. If $\cal U$ is open in $Y$, $\pi^{-1}[{\cal U}]$ is open in $X$ isn't it?

Comment: You might also look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3865513/is-the-map-pi-continuous/3865901#3865901) and my answer to it.