# Is the map $\pi$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\mathbb R$ endowed with its usual topology $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb R}$ and let $\mathbb R\cup \{\infty\}$ be endowed with the following topology:

$$\mathcal{T}=\{\emptyset\}\cup \{\mathcal{U}\cup\{\infty\}: \mathcal{U}\in\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb R}\}.$$

Consider the subespace $X=\mathbb R\times \{0\}\cup \mathbb R\times (0, +\infty)$ of $\mathbb R^2$ with the induced topology. Define $\pi: X\rightarrow \mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ setting:

$$\pi(x, y)=\left\{\begin{array}{clc}
\infty & \textrm{se}& y\in (0, +\infty)\\
x & \textrm{se}& y=0
\end{array}\right..$$

Is it true that $\pi$ is continuous?

Notice that if $\mathcal{U}$ is open in $\mathcal{T}$ then $\mathcal{U}=\mathcal{V}\cup\{\infty\}$ where $\mathcal{V}\in\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb R}$. Then:

$$\pi^{-1}(\mathcal{U})=\pi^{-1}(\mathcal{V})\cup \pi^{-1}(\{\infty\})=\pi^{-1}(\mathcal{V})\cup \mathbb R\times (0, +\infty),$$ hence it suffices to show $\pi^{-1}(\mathcal{V})$ is open in $X$. Here lies the problem, because:

$$\pi^{-1}(\mathcal{V})=\mathcal{V}\times \{0\}$$ and this does not seem open in $X$, right?

Did I make any mistake or $\pi$ is not continuous?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\varnothing\ne U\in\mathcal{T}$. As you say, $U=\{\infty\}\cup V$ for some $V\in\mathcal{T}_{\Bbb R}$, so

$$\pi^{-1}[U]=\big(V\times\{0\}\big)\cup\big(\Bbb R\times(0,\to)\big)\,,$$

but this actually **is** open in $X$: $X=\Bbb R\times[0,\to)$, and

$$\pi^{-1}[U]=\big(V\times[0,\to)\big)\cup\big(\Bbb R\times(0,\to)\big)\,,$$

which is an open subset of $\Bbb R\times[0,\to)$, because it’s the intersection with $X$ of $(V\times\Bbb R)\cup\big(\Bbb R\times(0,\to)\big)$, an open set in $\Bbb R^2$.